# FactoryFactory Facility in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, factory, typed-factory-facility

I make extensive use of the [interface-based Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) in Windsor, but there are times when I must pass a lot of arguments to a factory around with the factory itself.  I'd much prefer to create a *factory factory* with these arguments so that I don't need to muddy up the constructors of objects more than I need to.

For example, assume I have this factory (registered with Castle using [`.AsFactory()`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx#Registering_factories_10)):

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    IFoo Create(IBar bar, IBaz baz);
}
```

If I want to create an `IFoo`, I'd do something like this:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public DummyClass(IFooFactory fooFactory, IBarProvider barProvider, IBaz baz)
    {
        fooFactory.Create(barProvider.Bar, baz);
    }
}
```

What I'd like is to be able to define this:

```
public interface IFooFactoryFactory
{
    IFooFactory Create(IBaz baz);
}
```

**And register it with Castle using `AsFactory()`.**  This way I could then remove the vagabond parameter `baz` if I constructed `IFooFactory` like so:

```
public void CreateDummies(IFooFactoryFactory fooFactoryFactory, IBarProvider barProvider, IBaz baz)
{
     IFooFactory fooFactory = fooFactoryFactory.Create(baz);
     var dummy = dummyFactory.Create(fooFactory, barProvider);
}
```

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible in Windsor's current release, but I thought I'd ask in case I'm missing it.

Comment: Can you not just instantiate an IFooFactory with the instance of IBaz that you want to persist, and register that in the container? Is there more than one instance of the IFooFactory available to use?

Comment: @RJLohan I can, but then I'd have more code to test.  I'd prefer to let Windsor create the `IFooFactoryFactory` and the `IFooFactory`.

Comment: Why do you need a barProvider, couldn't you just register IBar with some lifetime so that you always get the correct one ? That way you could have an IFooFactory which only takes IBaz as argument and you could drop the factoryfactory.

Comment: @Marwijn This is a contrived example, but nevertheless... If I need a specific transient `IBar` instance (e.g. one that is created/provided by the `IBarProvider`), I have to do it this way (pass it via factory argument).  And I'm definitely not going to register the `IBar` in the container just before every time I call `IFooFactory.Create()`

Comment: I was certainly not thinking about registering it just in time. But more in the direction of a Boundend or Scoped lifetime.

Comment: @Marwijn Doing it that way (with either lifestyle) introduces a coupling that is not obvious to the users of the `IFooFactory`.